# I can't include attribute in my XML Schema. (http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance used)

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I'm trying to make a XML Schema to validate my XML's, for the first time.

Start of my XML (Notice "`-instance`" and "`SectionNumber="0"`") :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CrystalReport 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail  
                   http://www.businessobjects.com/products/xml/CR2008Schema.xsd" 
  xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"
>

  <ReportHeader>
    <Section SectionNumber="0">
      <Text Name="Text9">
        ...
```

My XML Schema (Notice line 2, 3 and 20) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsi:schema  id="XMLSchema_varslings1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail">

    <xsi:element name="CrystalReport" type="CrystalReportType"/>

    <xsi:complexType name="CrystalReportType">
        <xsi:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsi:element name="ReportHeader"  type="ReportHeaderType"/>
        </xsi:sequence>
    </xsi:complexType>

    <xsi:complexType name="ReportHeaderType">
        <xsi:sequence>
            <xsi:element name="Section" type="SectionType"/>
            <!-- This is line 19....................................... -->
            <xsi:attribute name="SectionNumber" type="xsi:Integer"/>
        </xsi:sequence>
    </xsi:complexType>

    <xsi:complexType name="SectionType">
        <xsi:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsi:element name="Text" type="TextType" />
        </xsi:sequence>
    </xsi:complexType>

    <xsi:complexType name="TextType">
        <xsi:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsi:element name="TextValue" type="xsi:string" />
        </xsi:sequence>
    </xsi:complexType>
</xsi:schema>
```

I get this error, that I can't resolve:
"`The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be <schema> and its namespace should be 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.`"

If I remove "`-instance`" from the schema, I get rid of the above error but then I can't use the code for the attribute "`<xsi:attribute name="SectionNumber" type="xsi:Integer"/>`".

I don't even know if my real problem is the `-instance` part or there is another way to write/include the attributes in the schema. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing two namespaces: `XMLSchema` and `XMLSchema-instance`. Those two serve different purposes, `XMLSchema` (usually with the prefix `xs`) is used to *declare* your schema. That's why your XSD file doesn't work without it.

The namespace `XMLSchema-instance` (usually with the prefix `xsi`) is used when you want to *use* some XML Schema in your document. For example, the `schemaLocation` prefix is in this namespace.

The type `integer` (lower-case `i`) is in the `XMLSchema` namespace, so you have to use it as such.

Also, you have incorrect order of elements. `<xs:attribute>` should be after `<xs:sequence>`.

So, your schema should look like this:

```
<xs:schema id="XMLSchema_varslings1"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="urn:crystal-reports:schemas:report-detail">

  …

  <xs:complexType name="ReportHeaderType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Section" type="SectionType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="SectionNumber" type="xs:integer"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

I have also changed the namespace prefix to `xs`, because it makes sense, but technically it's not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, it's a really good answer. It makes alot of sense. You mean you changed the prefixes to `xs` and not `ns` right? I'll start testing right away.

Comment: Also, now it make sense, why all I read used `xs` and not `xsi` like I did haha :)

Comment: Sorry it's not possible for me to give you more than +1 (otherwise I would, you corrected me multiply times) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I found this:

[Link to w3](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance)

"This schema should never be used as such: the XML Schema Recommendation forbids the declaration of attributes in this namespace"

I guess I'm in trouble then because I need to change the XML then. The problem is that the XML is generated from a old program we have. Can anyone confirm / not confirm I found the solution or else I would appriciate anyone elses answers?